# Automatically obtaining linear quivers with relations from a list using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a list L that looks for example as follows:

```
L=[ 5, [ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], 
  [ (1)*a1*a2*a3, (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3*a4 ] ]
```

The first entry is a number, here it is 5. The other entries are lists of the form for example
`[ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ]`.

From this lists with n entries we can generate n-1 pictures, where each of those n-1 pictures looks as follows corresponding to a list of the form `[ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ]` :

Draw a quiver (=directed graph) with z vertices (z is the first number in the list L) which is a linear oriented line with arrows named from `a_1 to a_{z-1}`.

Now input the relations, for example `[ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ]` into this quiver.

The example `[ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ]` should give the following tikz picture (that I generated with the quiver application for tikz, you can copy paste the link to obtain the picture in the quiverapp editor):

% `https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNSxbMCwwLCIxIl0sWzEsMCwiMiJdLFsyLDAsIjMiXSxbMywwLCI0Il0sWzQsMCwiNSJdLFswLDEsImFfMSJdLFsxLDIsImFfMiJdLFsyLDMsImFfMyJdLFszLDQsImFfNCJdLFsxLDMsIiIsMSx7ImN1cnZlIjozLCJzdHlsZSI6eyJib2R5Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJkYXNoZWQifX19XSxbMiw0LCIiLDEseyJjdXJ2ZSI6Mywic3R5bGUiOnsiYm9keSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiZGFzaGVkIn19fV1d`

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
    \arrow["{a_1}", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{a_2}", from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow["{a_3}", from=1-3, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{a_4}", from=1-4, to=1-5]
    \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-2, to=1-4]
    \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-3, to=1-5]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

So the input should be the list L and the output should be n-1 such quivers with the relations corresponding to the entries of the list L in the given order.

> Question 1: Is there an easy way to automatically do this using Tikz?

Here a minimal example of one pictures of a linear quiver with relations that compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

{\tikzset{curve/.style={settings={#1},to path={(\tikztostart)
    .. controls ($(\tikztostart)!\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    and ($(\tikztostart)!1-\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    settings/.code={\tikzset{quiver/.cd,#1}
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/quiver/##1}}},
    quiver/.cd,pos/.initial=0.35,height/.initial=0}
    
% https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNSxbMCwwLCIxIl0sWzEsMCwiMiJdLFsyLDAsIjMiXSxbMywwLCI0Il0sWzQsMCwiNSJdLFswLDEsImFfMSJdLFsxLDIsImFfMiJdLFsyLDMsImFfMyJdLFszLDQsImFfNCJdLFsxLDMsIiIsMSx7ImN1cnZlIjozLCJzdHlsZSI6eyJib2R5Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJkYXNoZWQifX19XSxbMiw0LCIiLDEseyJjdXJ2ZSI6Mywic3R5bGUiOnsiYm9keSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiZGFzaGVkIn19fV1d
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
    \arrow["{a_1}", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{a_2}", from=1-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow["{a_3}", from=1-3, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{a_4}", from=1-4, to=1-5]
    \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-2, to=1-4]
    \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-3, to=1-5]
\end{tikzcd}\]



\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help!

edit:

Here is a complete example:

The list `[ 4, [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a1*a2 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3 ] ]` should give the following tikz picture of 4 linear oriented quivers with the corresponding relations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

{\tikzset{curve/.style={settings={#1},to path={(\tikztostart)
    .. controls ($(\tikztostart)!\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    and ($(\tikztostart)!1-\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    settings/.code={\tikzset{quiver/.cd,#1}
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/quiver/##1}}},
    quiver/.cd,pos/.initial=0.35,height/.initial=0}
    
      % https://q.uiver.app/#q=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

  

    \[\begin{tikzcd}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4
        \arrow["{a_1}", from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["{a_2}", from=1-2, to=1-3]
        \arrow["{a_3}", from=1-3, to=1-4]
        \arrow["{a_1}", from=2-1, to=2-2]
        \arrow["{a_2}", from=2-2, to=2-3]
        \arrow["{a_3}", from=2-3, to=2-4]
        \arrow["{a_1}", from=3-1, to=3-2]
        \arrow["{a_2}", from=3-2, to=3-3]
        \arrow["{a_3}", from=3-3, to=3-4]
        \arrow["{a_1}", from=4-1, to=4-2]
        \arrow["{a_2}", from=4-2, to=4-3]
        \arrow["{a_3}", from=4-3, to=4-4]
        \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-1, to=1-3]
        \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=1-2, to=1-4]
        \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=2-2, to=2-4]
        \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=3-1, to=3-3]
        \arrow[curve={height=18pt}, dashed, from=4-1, to=4-4]
    \end{tikzcd}\]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thank you for your comment. You mean that the picture is visible on this site? I will try to do it now. You can also use the link to see the picture in the quiver app editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thank you. I added an example that compiles now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `\regex_extract_all:nnN` is used to obtain the lists with brackets. These are stored in `\l__Mare_arrows_seq`. Then a loop is formed with `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn`. The `\arrow` commands are constructed with `\tl_build_put_right:Nn` and `\tl_build_put_right:Ne`. These are inserted in the `tikzcd` environment with `\l__Mare_arrows_tl`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { en }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_build_put_right:Nn { Ne }
\seq_new:N \l__Mare_arrows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__Mare_indices_seq
\tl_new:N \l__Mare_arrow_tl
\tl_new:N \l__Mare_arrows_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \quiver } { r[] }
  {
    \regex_extract_all:nnN { \[[^\[\]]+\] } {#1} \l__Mare_arrows_seq
    \tl_build_begin:N \l__Mare_arrows_tl
      \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__Mare_arrows_seq
        {
          \tl_set:Ne \l__Mare_arrow_tl {##2}
          \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__Mare_arrow_tl { [ }
          \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__Mare_arrow_tl { ] }
          \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__Mare_arrow_tl { a }
          \clist_map_inline:en { \l__Mare_arrow_tl }
            {
              \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__Mare_indices_seq { * } {####1}
              \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__Mare_arrows_tl { \arrow }
              \tl_build_put_right:Ne \l__Mare_arrows_tl
                {
                  [
                    bend~right ,
                    dashed ,
                    from = ##1 - \seq_item:Nn \l__Mare_indices_seq { 2 } ,
                    to = ##1 - \int_eval:n { \seq_item:Nn \l__Mare_indices_seq { -1 } + 1 }
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    \tl_build_end:N \l__Mare_arrows_tl
    \begin { tikzcd } [ ampersand~replacement = \& ]
      \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l__Mare_arrows_seq }
        {
          \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_item:nn {#1} { 1 } - 1 }
            { ####1 \arrow [ r , " { a \c_math_subscript_token {####1} } " ] \& }
          \clist_item:nn {#1} { 1 }
          \int_compare:nNnF {##1} = { \seq_count:N \l__Mare_arrows_seq }
            { \\ }%no \\ for the last row
        }
      \l__Mare_arrows_tl
    \end { tikzcd }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\quiver[ 5, [ (1)*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3, (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a1*a2, (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], 
  [ (1)*a1*a2*a3, (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a2*a3*a4 ], [ (1)*a1*a2 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3 ], [ (1)*a1*a2*a3*a4 ] ]$
\end{document}
```